# Eclipse, error: Couldn't write file "...." (permission denied)

Tags: eclipse, maven, permission-denied

I have a maven project on eclipse linked with a  git repository. When I try to save files, eclipse tells me that it couldn't save the file because the permission is denied. I noticed that it happened after I remove some class from my project.

Comment: I tried to modify the file's permission but nothing changed.

Comment: After refreshing project, it works!

Answer (score 5):

This is because according to your system, you are not the owner of the particular directory. If you are using ubuntu here is what you can do:
Login as root user to do this, in terminal enter command

> "sudo su"

provide your password.
Then navigate till the directory and enter command

> "chown -v user_name -R folder_name/"

This worked for me hope will do for you.